# Numpy ndarray assignment issue

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I am not able to figure what out what is wrong with this piece of code. Could you please help me understand what is going wrong and how to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
T = np.random.randint(0,5,(3,2,3))
print(T)
print(T[0,0])
print(T[0,0].sum())
T[0,0] = T[0,0]/T[0,0].sum()
print(T)
```

Output i get:

```
[[[4 1 3]
  [1 4 4]]

 [[0 0 4]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[2 4 2]
  [2 1 4]]]
[4 1 3]
8
[0.5   0.125 0.375]
[[[0 0 0]
  [1 4 4]]

 [[0 0 4]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[2 4 2]
  [2 1 4]]]
```

Output i expect:

```
[[[4 1 3]
  [1 4 4]]

 [[0 0 4]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[2 4 2]
  [2 1 4]]]
[4 1 3]
8
[0.5   0.125 0.375]
[[[0.5   0.125 0.375]
  [1 4 4]]

 [[0 0 4]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[2 4 2]
  [2 1 4]]]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you justify that row of floats, `[0.5   0.125 0.375]` in an integer array?

Comment: Feel like an idiot now, guess that is the result of coding in wee hours of night. Thanks for bringing sanity to my life again. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is of type `int` (calling `randint`) and you try to assign `float` to it which will round numbers to `int` in it. If you want to keep the values as `float`, convert your array to `float` as well.

```
T = T.astype(np.float)
T[0,0] = T[0,0]/T[0,0].sum()
print(T)
```

The example is different, because it is created randomly, but gives you the ides:

```
[[[0.   0.75 0.25]
  [1.   4.   0.  ]]

 [[1.   4.   0.  ]
  [1.   3.   1.  ]]

 [[3.   2.   1.  ]
  [4.   0.   2.  ]]]
```